# How to export as CSV for selected period using AmCharts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-csv, amcharts

I have an AngularJS app where I have an amchart stock javascript chart. The chart allows the user to select the period of data they want to view, (1-3 months) and allows the user to export their data as CSV or JSON. Whenever I export the data it returns the full 3 months of data. Is there anyway to have the graph export data that correlates to selected period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting [`exportSelection`](https://github.com/amcharts/export#complete-list-of-available-export-settings) to true in your export config:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "exportSelection": true
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/cfa0dc742002478e3a98b5b28d6d3918?editors=0010)